# Get unique results from SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I have very simple data table

```
   pk | id1 | id2 
   1  |  1  |  2
   2  |  1  |  3
   3  |  10 |  2
   4  |  10 |  3
   5  |  20 |  2
   6  |  20 |  3
```

I need unique results from the table, 
I need a set of combination pairs between id1 and id2 where all elements in a set are unique

Accteptable results of SELECT from sample table are:

```
1| 1|2
4|10|3
```

or

```
2| 1|3
3|10|2
```

or

```
1| 1|2
6|20|3
```

or

```
2| 1|3
5|20|2
```

or

```
3|10|2
6|20|3
```

or

```
4|10|3
5|20|2
```

But I need only the first occurrence of possible results.
Using of `GROUP BY id1` or `id2` do not make job which I need.

Comment: Please follow this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Comment: Don't mind the downvoters. There's a bunch of folk on Stackoverflow who vote down any question they don't understand !

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem? Please don't forget to accept it, or tell me what's missing otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Try this:**

`DataTable newTable = view.ToTable(true, "column1", "column2",...);`
Will do your task.

**Below is the Example**

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("NewTable");

DataColumn column = new DataColumn("ID1", typeof(System.Int32));
table.Columns.Add(column);

column = new DataColumn("ID2", typeof(System.Int32));
table.Columns.Add(column);

DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = new object[] { 1, 2};
table.Rows.Add(row);

row = table.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = new object[] { 2, 3};
table.Rows.Add(row);

row = table.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = new object[] { 10, 2};
table.Rows.Add(row);

row = table.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = new object[] { 10, 2 };
table.Rows.Add(row);

row = table.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = new object[] { 20, 2};
table.Rows.Add(row);

row = table.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = new object[] { 20, 3};
table.Rows.Add(row);

// Mark all rows as "accepted". Not required
// for this particular example.
table.AcceptChanges();

DataView view = new DataView(table);
view.Sort = "ID1";

DataTable newTable = view.ToTable(true, "ID1", "ID2");

Console.WriteLine("New table name: " + newTable.TableName);


foreach (DataRow row1 in newTable.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    for(int x = 0; x < newTable.Columns.Count; x++)
    {
        Console.Write(row1[x].ToString() + " ");
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

However your question is still not clear, So I'm not sure  that it will fulfill your requirements. Add comments if it is a solution to your prob.

Answer (score 0):

Right here you are. This has been an interesting one. This code is working for me. I've put in a bit of random so you get a different result each time.

```
/*create table SourceData (
pk int,
id1 int,
id2 int
)
insert into SourceData (pk,id1,id2)
    values
    ( 1  ,  1  ,  2),
    ( 2  ,  1  ,  3),
    ( 3  ,  10 ,  2),
    ( 4  ,  10 ,  3),
    ( 5  ,  20 ,  2),
    ( 6  ,  20 ,  3)
    */

Create table #temp1 (pk int not null);
--Pick a first row at random
insert into #temp1 (pk)
    select top 1 pk from SourceData
    order by NEWID()
;
declare @KeepGoing int = 1;
-- for as long as we keep finding new rows in SourceData
WHILE( @KeepGoing > 0 )
BEGIN

    insert into  #temp1 (pk)
        -- find 1 row in SourceData where no value matches an existing picked row
        select top 1 pk from SourceData
        where id1 not in (select id1 from #temp1 T inner join SourceData SD on T.pk = SD.pk)
        and id2 not in (select id2 from #temp1 T inner join SourceData SD on T.pk = SD.pk)
        order by NEWID()

    SET @KeepGoing = @@ROWCOUNT
END
-- display results
select SD.* from #temp1 T inner join SourceData SD on T.pk = SD.pk
drop table #temp1
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should do the trick

```
select min(pk), id1, id2 from table_name group by id1, id2;
```